# Wierd results while trying to build an URI for HTTPGET

Tags: android, hashmap, uri, http-get

I'm trying to build an `URL` by adding some parameters to my `BASEURL`:
The problem is the parameters are added to my `BASEURL` in disorder, and characters as `é` are replaced by weird stuffs like `%C3%A9`

```
String BASEURI="myBaseUri";
void getParameters()
{
    HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();              
   final String login = ((EditText)alertDialogRegister.findViewById(R.id.regLogin)).getText().toString();
   final String password= ((EditText)alertDialogRegister.findViewById(R.id.regPassword)).getText().toString();
   final String passwordConfirm= ((EditText)alertDialogRegister.findViewById(R.id.regPasswordConfirm)).getText().toString();
   final String firstName= ((EditText)alertDialogRegister.findViewById(R.id.regPrenom)).getText().toString();
   final String lastName= ((EditText)alertDialogRegister.findViewById(R.id.regNom)).getText().toString();
       final String sexe=((RadioButton)alertDialogRegister.findViewById(((RadioGroup)alertDialogRegister.findViewById(R.id.regSexe)).getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
   final String email= ((EditText)alertDialogRegister.findViewById(R.id.regEmail)).getText().toString();
   final String telephone= ((EditText)alertDialogRegister.findViewById(R.id.regPhone)).getText().toString();
   final String adresse= ((EditText)alertDialogRegister.findViewById(R.id.regAddress)).getText().toString();
   final String civilite=((RadioButton)alertDialogRegister.findViewById(((RadioGroup)alertDialogRegister.findViewById(R.id.regCivilite)).getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
    map.put("rquest","addUser");
    map.put("login", login);
    map.put("password", password);
    map.put("firstname", firstName);
    map.put("lastname", lastName);
    map.put("sex", sexe);
    map.put("situation", civilite);
    map.put("email", email);
    map.put("address", adresse);
    registeruser(map);

}
```

---

```
 public void registeruser(HashMap<String,String> map)
    {  
        Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(BASEURI).buildUpon();
        builder.appendPath("api.php");
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry:map.entrySet())
        {
        builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
        }
        Uri builtUri = builder.build();
        Log.i("Hossam", builtUri.toString());
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(builder.toString());  

        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();  
        String result = null;
        try {  
            result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);  
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();  
        String tag = null;
        //Log.i("http response", result);  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order issue, is because you are using a Map, and in Java Maps are unordered and unsorted type of collection, unless you use either LinkedHashMap or TreeMap which cost way more in performance than regular List, if you want specific order you must go for List, other way the Map will always return the values in an unordered way, and related to the special characters is because your URL contains them, and by default the URL is coneverted to its encoded version of them since they can only be ASCII, here is the list of the URL Encoded characters... http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

Comment: Yeah i see, one little thing you need to modify in you answer before i upvote/accept your answer, `LinkedHashMap` keeps the insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

Your characters `é`  does not belong to ASCII character-set.

URLs can only contains ASCII character-set.
Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.

URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.
URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a + sign.

Source:[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)